# Simple SQL count with distinct query

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a table(Student) with the entities 'StudentID' and 'ProgrammeID' in phpmyadmin. I am trying to figure out how to do a query which lists the number of students in each particular programme and also displays the programmeID itself, but cant seem to figure it out.

```
SELECT count(`StudentID`) FROM Student WHERE `ProgrammeID` = DISTINCT
```

gives a synthax error near distinct.

Im sure its fairly straightforward but its beyond me at this hour.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to count the number of `Student` for every `ProgrammeID`. In this case, use `GROUP BY` clause.

```
SELECT ProgrammeID, COUNT(StudentID) TotalStudentCount
FROM   Student 
GROUP  BY ProgrammeID
```

Comment: That is exactly what i wanted, finally i can get some sleep! Cheers